# Rolling Statistics on Image Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, imagefilter

I need to calculate the local statistics of a image depending on a 2D Window block defined by the user. Stats include : Mean, Variance, Skew, Kurtosis. I need to traverse through each pixel of the image and find the neighboring pixels depending on the window size.

The code that I used was:

```
scipy.ndimage.generic_filter(array,numpy.var,size=3)
```

But the performance through this is very low. I even tried strides-numpy but that too isn't showing much difference (wasn't able to compute skewness, kurtosis). I'm not familiar with Cython so have not ventured into that option.
So is there any other way to accomplish this without Cython?

Answer (score 3):

The reason `uniform_filter()` is so much faster than `generic_filter()` is due to Python -- for `generic_filter()`, Python gets called for each pixel, while for `uniform_filter()`, the whole image is processed in native code.  (I found OpenCV's `boxFilter()` even faster than `uniform_filter()`, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36266187/1628638) to a "window variance" question.)

In the remainder of this answer, I show how to do a **skew** calculation using `uniform_filter()`, which dramatically speeds up a `generic_filter()`-based version such as:

```
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage, scipy.stats as st
ndimage.generic_filter(img, st.skew, size=(1,5))
```

SciPy's `st.skew()` (see, e.g., [v0.17.0](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.17.0/scipy/stats/stats.py#L1199)) appears to calculate the skew as

```
m3 / m2**1.5
```

where `m3 = E[(X-m)**3]` (the third central moment), `m2 = E[(X-m)**2]` (the variance), and `m = E[X]` (the mean).

To use `uniform_filter()`, one has to write this in terms of *raw moments* such as `m3p = E[X**3]` and `m2p = E[X**2]` (a prime symbol is usually used to distinguish the raw moment from the central one):

```
m3 = E[(X-m)**3] = ... = m3p - 3*m*m2p + 2*m**3
m2 = E[(X-m)**2] = ... = m2p - m*m
```

(In case my "..." skips too much, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18422519/1628638) has the full derivation for m2.)  Then one can implement `skew()` using `uniform_filter()` (or `boxFilter()` for some additional speedup):

```
def winSkew(img, wsize):
  imgS = img*img
  m, m2p, m3p = (ndimage.uniform_filter(x, wsize) for x in (img, imgS, imgS*img))
  mS = m*m
  return (m3p-3*m*m2p+2*mS*m)/(m2p-mS)**1.5
```

Compared to `generic_filter()`, `winSkew()` gives a **654-fold** speedup on the following example on my machine:

```
In [185]: img = np.random.randint(0, 256, (500,500)).astype(np.float)

In [186]: %timeit ndimage.generic_filter(img, st.skew, size=(1,5))
1 loops, best of 3: 14.2 s per loop

In [188]: %timeit winSkew(img, (1,5))
10 loops, best of 3: 21.7 ms per loop
```

And the two calculations give essentially identical results:

```
In [190]: np.allclose(winSkew(img, (1,5)), ndimage.generic_filter(img, st.skew, size=(1,5)))
Out[190]: True
```

The code for a Kurtosis calculation can be derived the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `generic_filter()` cannot assume that your filter is separable along the `x` or `y` axes. Thus it must operate as a true 2D filter rather than a series of two 1D filters, so run-time will be much slower.

The mean filter and is equivalent (I think) to the `uniform_filter()`, which if you read the documentation, is implemented as a series of two 1d uniform filters.

I compared timing via this code block:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from scipy import misc
baboonfile = '/Users/curt/Downloads/BaboonRGB.jpg'  #local download of http://read.pudn.com/downloads169/sourcecode/graph/texture_mapping/776733/Picture/BaboonRGB__.jpg
im = misc.imread(baboonfile)

meanfilt2D = ndi.generic_filter(im, np.mean, size=[3, 3, 1])
%timeit meanfilt2D = ndi.generic_filter(im, np.mean, size=[3, 3, 1])
print meanfilt2D.shape

meanfiltU = ndi.uniform_filter(im, size=[3, 3, 1])
%timeit meanfiltU = ndi.uniform_filter(im, size=[3, 3, 1])
print meanfiltU.shape
```

The output of that block was:

```
1 loops, best of 3: 5.22 s per loop
(512, 512, 3)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.8 ms per loop
(512, 512, 3)
```

so true two-dimensional `generic_filter()` takes 5 seconds for a small image but the two-pass 1D `uniform_filter()` takes only milliseconds.  (N.B.: The difference image meanfilt2D-meanfiltU was not identically zero, but the maximum element was 2; I think the differences are caused by rounding and the imprecise datatype (`uint8`) used for `im`.)

For variance and other filters, you should see [this old Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361595/calculating-variance-image-python) which answers a highly related question.

Comment: Thanks. This does speed up calculation of variance and mean, but I still need a way to speed up calculation of skewness and kurtosis. Numpy doesn't support them and they can't be applied in strides output since scipy.stats.skew & kurtosis support application over a single axis